# how take text from selected listview item

Tags: android, listview, text

i'm using a listview which is populated by a database. I should take text from selected listView item but i don't know what method should i use. Can you explain me please?

Here my code:

```
    public class UserActivity extends ActionBarActivity{

    public static ArrayList<String> ArrayofName = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ListView listView;
    public static String item_name = "";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.user_activity);

        DataHandler db = new DataHandler(this);
        List<Data> items = db.getTitle();

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, ArrayofName);

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {
                //here i should take text from selected item

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
       @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {
            String text = ArrayofName.get(position);
            //do whatever you want with the object "text"

        }
```